# How to use Weka model on Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, weka, bigdata

I am new to spark and scala.
I have 10 machine learning models which are trained using WEKA.

```
Now, i am moving my application to spark and want to use these models.
How can i use them into spark?
```

For prediction, which model to choose depends on the type of data coming.
How shall i design my application so that i don't have to load all 10 of them in memory together?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `classifiers` in weka are not `serializable` therefore you can only apply your models in a tricky way.

On the other hand, it is not clear why you want to apply weka based model in apache spark as you can also train spark based ML algorithms with MLLib (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html). 
It is well documented, and you can find a lot of useful examples.

Finally, I compered the performance of weka J48 decision tree and the spark decision tree model on the reuters data set.
It is a document classification problem, I evaulted the model on 10-fold cross validation manner. 
The F1 scores result of weka:

(ship, 0.5751879699248121)
(grain, 0.7714285714285716)
(money-fx, 0.7308567096285064)
(corn, 0.7334851936218679)
(trade, 0.7641325536062378)
(crude, 0.7815049864007253)
(earn, 0.9310115645354248)
(wheat, 0.7661870503597122)
(acq, 0.8078484438430312)
(interest, 0.6561743341404359)

And the results of spark:

(ship, 0.5307018372123027)
(grain, 0.7606432455706257)
(money-fx, 0.7476899173974012)
(corn, 0.7210280866934613)
(trade, 0.7607140827384508)
(crude, 0.7450426425908848)
(earn, 0.9337615148649243)
(wheat, 0.751148372254634)
(acq, 0.8009280204333529)
(interest, 0.6837952003315322)

As you can see, it is not a huge different between the two solution.
So, I recommend you to apply apache spark mllib!

Comment: Would you please elaborate the "tricky way". I need to use weka in Spark as a research project. But as you said, the Classifier class does not extend Serializable. How can I do this? Thank you.